# What does a[3] = (a[1], a[2]); mean?

Tags: c99

I am wondering what does `a[3] = (a[1], a[2]);` does in the following code. It returns `a[3] = 0`. And if I eliminate the parentheses, `a[3] = a[1]` and `a[2]` doesn't change its value.
Thank you!

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int a[4] = { 100, 200 }; 
    a[3] = (a[1], a[2]); // What happens here?
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a[3]` does not change its value, it is given `0` from the initialization

Comment: I haven't seen any expression like this before...like apparently a[3] is not a tuple or a set, so what's the function of the parentheses here? Thank you!

Comment: `a[3]` is assigned the last in the parenthesis the fist values are unused is is 0 because `a[2]` is 0

Answer (score 0):

> What does `a[3] = (a[1], a[2]);` mean?

You are assigning `a[3]` the result from an expression with the comma operator.

Try this example in a debugger and what is happening gets more clear

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   int a[10] = { 100, 200 ,-10,-20,-30 }; 
   a[3] = ( a[1]++,a[3]++,a[4]++ );
   printf("%d %d %d %d\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);
}
```

The first part of the expression gets executed, but in your example `a[1]` is ignored in this example it gets incremented, then `a[3]` gets assigned the last value in the parenthesis here `a[4]`

[See more in this answer to "How does the Comma Operator work"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19198977/391691)

Answer (score 0):

> a[3] = (a[1], a[2]); // What happens here?

When expressions are separated by commas, the last one is returned.

```c
int a = (1, 2, 3);
// a = 3
```